# And predicate filtering clojure

Tags: clojure, functional-programming

I have function that takes any amount of predicates and filters the seq for each one of them like this:

```
 (defn andp [& fns]
      (fn [& args]
        (every? #(apply % args) fns)))

(defn pred-and
      ([] "what to return")
      ([x] x)
      ([x y] (andp x y))
      ([x y & more]
          (reduce pred-and (pred-and x y) more)
        )
)
```

This works as expected for 1 2 or more params like this:

```
(filter (pred-and pos? odd?) [1 2 -4 0 6 7 -3]) => [1 7] // For one parameter

(filter (pred-and number? integer? pos? even?)             [1 0 -2
:a 7 "a" 2])                   => [2] // For two parameters
```

The problem is when I pass no parameters, it should return the original sequence how to do that?

`(filter (pred-and) [1 0 -2])                    => [1 0 -2]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as per the [docs](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/filter) filter

> returns a lazy sequence of the items in coll for which (pred item) returns true.

To get the original sequence, (pred item) must return true for every item.

`(fn [x] true)` should do the trick.

Comment: thanks it work just to ask I was returning true and it didn't worked but when I returned (fn [x] true) it worked why ?

Comment: The [spec](http://iloveponies.github.io/120-hour-epic-sax-marathon/one-function-to-rule-them-all.html#exercise-11) says:

> If no parameters are given, return a predicate that always returns true

A predicate is function whose value is used in a boolean context

Comment: `(constantly true)` would be more idiomatic.